# Undoing iptables -F

Tags: 22.04, iptables

How do I undo the `iptables -F` command on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS?

From iptables [manual](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man8/iptables.8.html#options):

> `-F`, `--flush [chain]`
> Flush  the  selected chain (all the chains in the table if none is given).  This is equivalent to deleting all the rules one by one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you ran `iptables -F` without saving your `iptables` rules somewhere, there's no restoring them.  There's no backup file, no backup copy, for such a command.  Similar to in SQL that unless you have backups if you do a bad `UPDATE` that erases everything, you're hosed.

The only option you have here is to manually restore your rules you had one by one, or use a backup of the rules if you had them.  If you don't have a backup, then there's nothing you can do - and it's time to rebuild your rules manually from scratch.

---

Note that **by default there is no firewall configured on Ubuntu installations**.  If you are looking, however, for a good basic ruleset, you should instead consider installing `ufw` and doing `sudo ufw enable`.  And then allow whatever ports you need still in the ruleset.  This will give a pretty good all-around 'protect the system' setup for the average user.

Comment: Thank you Thomas, I understand what you are saying. Except for one single rule that I had manually input there were none to my knowledge. I'm running a Ubuntu 22.04 Desktop, are there some ```standard``` rules that I should restore? Thank you in advance

Comment: @SO_32 No, there are no default firewall rules in a default installation.  I have a basic `iptables` ruleset I deploy on every machine I use, but the average user can just install `ufw` then use `sudo ufw enable` and then configure additional rules in `ufw` to allow traffic past a standard set of rules.

Comment: Thank you very much, you can copy your comment to the answer section if you wish
See ya